# How to continually consume from Kafka topic using spring webflux?

Tags: java, spring-webflux, spring-kafka, project-reactor

I have a `spring-webflux` handler named `WordListenerHandler` which I can request a HTTP GET from the browser. This request is a stream of `Long` using `Flux`: `.body(Flux.interval(Duration.ofSeconds(1)).log(), Long.class)` so it continually update the HTML without refreshing the page. I want to show the messages of a kafka topi instead of the stream of Long values. So I have the consumer method `onMessage(ConsumerRecord<String, String> consumerRecord)` which is receiving messages and I am populating a `Queue<String> stringStream`. My idea is to use this queue on the HTTP GET method with `Flux.fromStream`. But is is static and I have to refresh the browser to see the updates. How do make the HTTP GET stream continually get data?

```
@Component
public class WordListenerHandler {

    private final String WORDS_STREAMING_OUTPUT_TOPIC_NAME = "streaming-words-output-topic";

    Queue<String> stringStream = new LinkedList<String>();

    public Mono<ServerResponse> fluxWordCountStream(ServerRequest serverRequest) {

        return ServerResponse.ok()
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_STREAM_JSON)

                 // DOES NOT WORK. i HAVE TO REFRESH THE BROWSER
                .body(Flux.fromStream(stringStream.stream()), String.class);

               // THIS WORKS AND I CAN CONTINUALLY SEE MY BROWSER UPDATE WITHOUT REFRESHING IT
               // .body(Flux.interval(Duration.ofSeconds(1)).log(), Long.class);
    }

    @KafkaListener(topics = {WORDS_STREAMING_OUTPUT_TOPIC_NAME})
    public void onMessage(ConsumerRecord<String, String> consumerRecord) throws JsonProcessingException {
        log.info("ConsumerRecord received: {}", consumerRecord);

        String message = consumerRecord.key() + " : " + consumerRecord.value() + "\n";
        stringStream.add(message);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend to look into a `Sink` Reactor's API: https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#sinks

So, your `@KafkaListener` is going to dump received data into a shared `Sinks.Many` in a back-pressure manner.

And your `MediaType.APPLICATION_STREAM_JSON` would just use an `asFlux()` from that sink.

I believe your problem that `stringStream.stream()` from that collection doesn't give a live object, but rather a snapshot of the current state of the collection.  So, that's indeed looks natural that you need to refresh request to get an update state from the collection.

Comment: thanks. I used the `multicast()` as `Sinks.Many<String> replaySink = Sinks.many().multicast().onBackpressureBuffer();` and changed the body to `.body(replaySink.asFlux().log(), String.class)`. I think it is that what you mean. Did you think different of this?

Comment: No, that's perfect!

Answer (score 0):

Try using a `LinkedBlockingQueue` instead of a `LinkedList` (which is not thread-safe).

```java
 * <p>The iterators returned by this class's {@code iterator} and
 * {@code listIterator} methods are <i>fail-fast</i>: if the list is
 * structurally modified at any time after the iterator is created, in
 * any way except through the Iterator's own {@code remove} or
 * {@code add} methods, the iterator will throw a {@link
 * ConcurrentModificationException}.  Thus, in the face of concurrent
 * modification, the iterator fails quickly and cleanly, rather than
 * risking arbitrary, non-deterministic behavior at an undetermined
 * time in the future.
```

Comment: no, did not worked. I think it is something to do with the spring-webflux and reactor project. Maybe, some how create a callable with the Flux. But I can't find in internet how to do that